# How to get Bookmarks toolbar information in JavaScript code?

Tags: toolbar, bookmarks

Is there any option for getting Bookmarks toolabr information from javascript code, i.e. 
Can we get information what are bookmarkleted in the Bookmarks toolbar [url, text etc.]?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the toolbar you are talking about (a browser bookmarks bar? which browser?) and the environment the JavaScript executes in.

Assuming the latter is "a webpage loaded in a browser", then the answer is 'no, that would be a horrific invasion of privacy and security risk'.

Other environments (e.g. a browser plugin) have different restrictions and may allow access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. This would be privacy violation.
Ex: your js read bookmarks information and send by ajax to your server.