# Is there a way to get bookmarks information WITHOUT using JS?

Tags: bookmarks

I've been doing some research on this and I'm still not sure if it's possible.

Is there any way to retrieve a user's bookmarks and display them on the page without violating their privacy? I saw these two threads talking about using JS to do this:

[How to get Bookmarks toolbar information in JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531025/how-to-get-bookmarks-toolbar-information-in-javascript-code)

[Show all bookmarks using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390555/show-all-bookmarks-using-javascript)

**I'm not thinking about doing this automatically, users would have to opt-in with a button that said "Display Bookmarks from My Browser" or something similar.**

Is it possible?

Comment: **Without** using JavaScript?  Well what are you imagining the alternatives to be?

Comment: It is impossible. That is a big security concern if you could do it. [AHHH missed the without, wish I could undo the close]

Comment: I don't understand how this is a violation of privacy, as long as you don't send that information anywhere else.

Comment: @sje397 well setting aside the mystery of doing it without JavaScript, if the information could be accessed and added to the page somehow, then anything could be done with it.

Comment: Just because this poster would not send it, does not mean someone else would send it. Look at the iphone and people uploading the users address book without their permission.

Comment: If the question title clearly says **WITHOUT** JS why is this tagged with JS then? Cleaning.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté because you can not do it with JavaScript, hence the without.

Comment: @epascarello the without makes sense, but the JS tag is for questions relating to JS. If OP doesn't want a JS solution, there is no reason to tag it with JS.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Sorry, this is the first time I've used StackOverflow. Wasn't sure what to tag it with...

Comment: No problem, next time you can tag it with `browser-extension`/`google-chrome-extension` or another language you'd accept an answer with (flash, java etc). `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without browser extensions. You could write a browser extension for the major browsers which retrieves the information and feeds it back to your page.

Comment: Thanks, looks like extensions are the only way to go.